# How to remove repeating code in this solution?

Tags: java, string, repeat

I have this code which compresses characters in the given string and replaces *repeated adjacent characters* with their **count**.

Consider the following example:

*Input:*

```
aaabbccdsa
```

*Expecting output:*

```
a3b2c2dsa
```

My code is working properly but I think repeating if condition can be removed.

```
public class Solution {
    public static String getCompressedString(String str) {
        String result = "";
        char anch = str.charAt(0);
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char ch = str.charAt(i);

            if (ch == anch) {
                count++;
            } else {
                if (count == 1) {           // from here
                    result += anch;
                } else {
                    result += anch + Integer.toString(count);                    
                }                         // to here

                anch = ch;
                count = 1;
            }

            if (i == str.length() - 1) {
                if (count == 1) {           // from here
                    result += anch;
                } else {
                    result += anch + Integer.toString(count);                    
                }                         // to here
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

In this solution code below is repeated two times

```
if (count == 1) {
    result += anch;
} else {
    result += anch + Integer.toString(count);                    
}
```

Please, **note**, I **don't** want to use a separate method for repeating logic.

Comment: brother please use two pointer technique,

i =0;
j=0;

and make code to run until I is less than string length.
while(i<str.length())

and in the while loop, please increment J until there is duplicate character, and keep track of the count. once you find the unique char. change value of i = j; and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```java
public static String getCompressedString(String str) {
        String result = "";
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (i + 1 < str.length() && str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i + 1)) {
                count++;
            } else {
                if (count == 1) {
                    result += str.charAt(i);
                } else {
                    result += str.charAt(i) + "" + count;
                    count = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I got rid of the repeated code, and it do as intended.

Comment: that's great edit but can you please explain your code? I am having a difficult time understanding this as this code is totally different from mine specially here `if (i + 1 < str.length() && str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i + 1))`.

Comment: @ækit Condition `i + 1 < str.length()` guards against accessing the index that doesn't exist (which would raise an exception), and the second part `str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i + 1)` checks whether the character at index `i` is equals to the next one.

Comment: Also, it would be better to use `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation because continuation based solution would have quadratic time complexity `O(n^2)` (**reminder:** strings are *immutable*, hence every concatenation results in redundant copying the contents of the previous string into a new one).

Answer (score 2):

You could do away with the if statements.

```java
   public static String getCompressedString(String str) {
        char[] a = str.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0,j=0; i<a.length; i=j){
           for(j=i+1;j < a.length && a[i] == a[j]; j++);
           sb.append(a[i]).append(j-i==1?"":j-i);
        }
        return sb.toString();
   }
}
```

Comment: I think this approach will have time complexity `O(n2)` instead `O(n)`

Comment: It's O(n).  The outer loop and the inner loop are really working together as one loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since, the body of the `else` and second `if` is the same, so we can merge them by updating the condition. The updated body of the function will be:

```java
String result = "";
char anch = str.charAt(0);
int count = 0;

char ch = str.charAt(0); // declare ch outside the loop, and initialize to avoid error
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    ch = str.charAt(i);

    if (ch == anch) {
        count++;
    }
    // check if the second condition is false, or if we are at the end of the string
    if (ch != anch || i == str.length() - 1) {
        if (count == 1) { // from here
            result += anch;
        } else {
            result += anch + Integer.toString(count);
        } // to here
        anch = ch;
        count = 1;
    }
}

// add the condition
// if count is greater than or
// if the last character added already to the result
if (count > 1 || (len < 2 || result.charAt(len - 2) != ch)) {
    result += ch;
}

return result;
```

#### Test Cases:

I have tested the solution on the following inputs:

```
aaabbccdsa -> a3b2c2dsa
aaab -> a3b
aaa -> a3
ab -> ab
aabbc -> a2b2c
```

#### Optional

If you want to make it shorter, you can update these 2 conditions.

```java
if (count == 1) { // from here
    result += anch;
} else {
    result += anch + Integer.toString(count);
} // to here
```

as

```java
result += anch;
if (count != 1) { // from here
    result += count;// no need to convert (implicit conversion)
} // to here
```

Comment: Your code returns `a3` for `aaab` instead of `a3b`.

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Comment: Now it returns `a3a` for `aaa` instead of `a3`.

Comment: I tried this same approach and was stuck with these same wrong answers.

Comment: It returns `a` for `ab`.

Comment: It is returning `a2b2` for `aabbc`

Comment: I have updated it and tested for all these use cases.

Answer (score 1):

***You can use this approach as explained below:***

**Code:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "aaabbccdsaccbbaaadsa";
        char[] strArray = s.toCharArray();
        char ch0 = strArray[0];
        int counter = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
            if(ch0 == strArray[i]){//check for consecutive characters and increment the counter
                counter++;
            } else { // when character changes while iterating
                sb.append(ch0 + "" + (counter > 1 ? counter : ""));
                counter = 1; // reset the counter to 1
                ch0 = strArray[i]; // reset the ch0 with the current character
            }
            if(i == strArray.length-1){// case for last element of the string
                sb.append(ch0 + "" + (counter > 1 ? counter : ""));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

**Sample Input/Output:**

```
Input:: aaabbccdsaccbbaaadsa
Output:: a3b2c2dsac2b2a3dsa

Input:: abcdaaaaa
Output:: abcda5
```

Comment: I don't want to use the function. my bad I should have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: @ækit It is just the extracted method , created to replace the common repeated code.

Comment: @ækit Updated the code with out using function.

Comment: @girdhar The code is repeted too in this answer and it is just shortened.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a single-statement solution using Stream API and regular expressions:

```
public static final Pattern GROUP_OF_ONE_OR_MORE = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1*");

public static String getCompressedString(String str) {
    
    return GROUP_OF_ONE_OR_MORE.matcher(str).results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .map(s -> s.charAt(0) + (s.length() == 1 ? "" : String.valueOf(s.length())))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getCompressedString("aaabbccdsa"));
    System.out.println(getCompressedString("awswwwhhhp"));
}
```

*Output:*

```
a3b2c2dsa   // "aaabbccdsa"
awsw3h3p    // "awswwwhhhp"
```

#### How does it work

A regular expression `"(.)\\1*"` is capturing a group `(.)` of identical characters of length `1` or greater. Where `.` - denotes any symbol, and `\\1` is a [back reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to the group.

Method [`Matcher.results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results()) *"returns a stream of match results for each subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern"*.

The only thing left is to evaluate the length of each group and transform it accordingly before collecting into the resulting String.

***Links:***

- <sup>A quick [tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) on Regular Expressions.</sup>
- <sup>Official tutorials on [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html)</sup>

Comment: OMG, that's too advance for me to understand and use in daily coding but that one is a great answer with an explanation. Can you PLEASE explain [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74085242/11974339) solution to me as this looks easy and Nibras haven't explained it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function which has the following 3 parameters : result, anch, count  .

something of this sort:

```
  private static String extractedFunction(String result,int count, char anch) {
               
                return count ==1 ? (result + anch) : (result +anch+Integer.toString(count) );
            }
```

make a function call from those two points like this :

```
result = extractedFunction(result,count,anch);
```

Comment: There is not need to pass the `result`. Simply do, `+=` when calling function

Comment: I don't want to use the function. my bad I should have mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static final Pattern PAT = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1*");

static String getCompressedString(String str) {
    return PAT.matcher(str)
        .replaceAll(m -> m.group(1)
            + (m.group().length() == 1 ? "" : m.group().length()));
}
```

Test cases:

```
@Test
public void testGetCompressedString() {
    assertEquals("", getCompressedString(""));
    assertEquals("a", getCompressedString("a"));
    assertEquals("abc", getCompressedString("abc"));
    assertEquals("abc3", getCompressedString("abccc"));
    assertEquals("a3b2c2dsa", getCompressedString("aaabbccdsa"));
}
```

The regular expression `"(.)\\1*"` used here matches any sequence of identical characters. `.replaceAll()` takes a lambda expression as an argument, evaluates the lambda expression each time the pattern matches, and replaces the original string with the result.
The lambda expression is passed a `Matcher` object containing the results of the match. Here we are receiving this object in the variable `m`. `m.group()` returns the entire matched substring, `m.group(1)` returns its first character.

If the input string is `"aaabbccdsa"`, it will be processed as follows.

```
m.group(1)   m.group()  returned by lambda
 a            aaa        a3
 b            bb         b2
 c            cc         c2
 d            d          d
 s            s          s
 a            a          a
```

Comment: Although you're not obliged to, it's a good practice from the perspective of the code of conduct, adding a mention when you're building your solution based on an existing one.